# Changing Background Images on Hover

Tags: css, background, hover

Screenshots [here](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BxVxYQK45ve2bjU0Q002cTlkLVU/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to animate a hover for a full screen background image using CSS. (Screenshots 1&2) but I also want my navigation to use my list class styles instead of the navigation I used from [this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/swap-your-pages-background-image-on-navigation-hover/) tutorial. (Screenshots 3&4). How can I get the classes to function as the adjacent sibling of the hovering images instead of the anchor?

Here is my CSS

```
html { 
background: url(scarf6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left:0%;
  z-index: -60;
  height:100%;
}

.container li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: -50;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
    top:0%;
    right:0%;
    left:100%;
    height:100%; 
    width:30px; 
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

li a:hover + img {
  left: 0px;
}

.red {
    background: #FF9999;
}

.white {
    background:#FAF0E6;
}

.pink {
    background: #FFC0CB;
}

.fuscia {
    background:#FF0033;
}

.l1 {
    height:4%;
    width:100%;
}

.l2 {
    height:.7%;
    width:100%;
}

.l3 {
    height:1.3%;
    width:100%;
}

.l4 {
    height:.7%;
    width:100%;
}

.l5 {
    height:1.3%;
    width:100%;
}

.l6 {
    height:.7%;
    width:100%;
}

.l7 {
    height:2.7%;
    width:100%;
}

.l8 {
    height:3.3%;
    width:100%;
}

.l9 {
    height:5.4%;
    width:100%;
}

.l10 {
    height:1.7%;
    width:100%;
}

.l11 {
    height:6.7%;
    width:100%;
}

.l12 {
    height:.8%;
    width:100%;
}

.l13 {
    height:4.2%;
    width:100%;
}

.l14 {
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
}

.l15 {
    height:5.8%;
    width:100%;
}

.l16 {
    height:3.3%;
    width:100%;
}

.l17 {
    height:2.5%;
    width:100%;
}

.l18 {
    height:1.1%;
    width:100%;
}

.l19 {
    height:34.5%;
    width:100%;
}

.l20 {
    height:3.1%;
    width:100%;
}

.l21 {
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
}

.l22 {
    height:6.2%;
    width:100%;
}
```

And my HTML

```
    <body>
<div class="container">
<div class="overlay">
<nav>
    <li class="l1 pink">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <img src="../../Cover.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <img class="hidden">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <img class="hidden">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Work</a>
        <img class="hidden">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <img class="hidden">
    </li>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the image as background-image of li or a. If you don't want to display image, place it via background-position to some not-make-sence area - e.g. if image if 32px high, place it:

```
background-position: left 32px;
```

It will make this image somehow invisible. (Important note: it's better, that element with this background is as display: block). Then, when hovering, you will place image back:

```
...:hover {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

I'm using this in many cases. Also when switching two images - in fact, both of them are in one image and only moving background-position when hovering.